# Impact of AD UPN Changes with SharePoint online permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, active-directory, migration, adfs

I am currently using a tool to migrate the on-premises content to SharePoint Online which is having ADFS and Dir Sync.

I saw a difference in the migrated and non migrated Office 365 AD accounts which is as explained below:

> non-migrated users accounts will be `domain\fistname_lastname` and
>   corresponding claims user will
>   `"i:0#.f|membership|fistname_lastname@domain.com`" but for
>   migrated office 365 accounts will be
>   `"i:0#.f|membership|fistname.lastname@domain.com"`

I would like to start moving the content before migrating the users and interested to know whether the SharePoint permissions will work normally even post migration of user accounts or not. I am even worried about the user specific fields such as modified by and created by.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

its depend upon the tools, usually if you migrate the users using the tools and then migrate the content it works like a charm. we did the same thing with sharegate for small set of user and no issue at all.

Update: I used tsunami tool to migrated from non sharepoint to cloud. In that project we migrate content then mapped the user...that help us in preserving the metadata...so as per your situation, I think you will be fine as per my experience...BTW which tool u are using?

Comment: the scenario that i mentioned was migrate the content first and then do the user move later. i can provide the mapping and update the user with changed upn value but i doubt whether it will work or not. most of our users were still not migrated yet so i would like to know.